# In SQL Server, How do I alter a table with records and add a unique datetime2 column to each row?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I need to add a timestamp column (`datetime2`) to an existing SQL Server database table.  If I create the column and use `getdate()` as the default value, I get duplicate values.  Since datetime2 has a high precision level, I thought it would eliminate that.  The engine may be too fast for what I want to do.

I cannot use `INSERT SELECT` because I need to have the same number of columns between the tables.  I cannot do a `SELECT INTO` because the previous table would need the datetime2, which is the original problem.  I also tried to create the Index at the same time as I created the column.  I couldn't because the the duplicates were created before the index was and the index (which is set to not allow duplicates).  I tried.  These failed.

How do I alter a table and add a new datetime2 column and have it populated with all unique values from getdate() (or some other date/time function)?

EDIT:  Based on Vamsi's comment I tried:

```
INSERT
SELECT
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000'

The duplicate key value is (2017-01-17 11:59:03.7030000)
```

I receive I was getting a duplicate, so I am doing something wrong.

EDIT:  Based on Laughing Vergil's (thanks) answer I did this,

```
DECLARE @dt datetime2(7),
    @dt2 datetime2(7),
    @create_dt datetime2(7)
declare db_cursor cursor for
select create_dt from mytable;
  OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
INTO @create_dt
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    SET @dt = GETDATE()
    WHILE @dt = @dt2
     BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.123'
        SET @dt = GETDATE()
     END
        update mytable set create_dt = @dt where current of db_cursor
    set @dt2 = @dt
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor into @create_dt
end
close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

Comment: one way would be to create a datetime2 column as nullable ,use a delay function to insert unique datetime values in to the column and once the column in not null , alter the column to make it non null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one time where a cursor is actually useful, **because** it adds a bit of delay that you can extend if needed. Try code like this:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime2(7),
    @dt2 datetime2(7)

DECLARE @MyTableID int

SET @dt = getdate()
SET @dt2 = GETDATE()

DECLARE cx CURSOR FOR 
SELECT MyTableID
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDateTimeColumn IS NULL
FOR UPDATE OF MyDateTimeColumn

Open cx
FETCH NEXT FROM cx
    INTO @MyTableID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @dt = GETDATE()
    WHILE @dt = @dt2
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.001'
        SET @dt = GETDATE()
    END
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET MyDateTimeColumn = @dt
    WHERE CURRENT OF cx 

    SET @dt2 = @dt
    FETCH NEXT FROM cx
        INTO @MyTableID
END
CLOSE cx
DEALLOCATE cx
```

Answer (score 1):

A quicker option might be to prepare a duplicated set, then alter it to be unique.

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. Prepare unique Dates in a parallel table then copy over.
2. Allow Duplicates, insert the records then alter the data to unique values, then alter the column to Unique.

Sample code below:

```
--Create a holding table
DROP TABLE dbo.TimeTest
CREATE TABLE dbo.TimeTest(ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
                            ,Val Float
                            ,Dtm DATETIME2 DEFAULT(GETDATE() )
                            );
GO

--Insert Test Data (creating duplicates)
INSERT INTO dbo.TimeTest(Val) VALUES(RAND())
GO 1000

--Show duplicate values
SELECT * FROM dbo.TimeTest ORDER BY ID

--Remove the Duplication
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    A.Dtm
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Dtm ORDER BY ID) AS Rnk
FROM 
    dbo.TimeTest A
    )
UPDATE cte
SET
    Dtm = DATEADD(MICROSECOND,Rnk-1,Dtm)

ALTER TABLE dbo.TimeTest ADD CONSTRAINT Dtm UNIQUE(Dtm)

--Show unique values
SELECT * FROM dbo.TimeTest ORDER BY ID
```